# Discount Calculator using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code to set a value to a html textbox the code works but the values appears and then disappear immediately.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
       var price=0, discount=0, afterDiscount=0;
        price = Number(document.discountCalculator.price.value);
        discount = Number(document.discountCalculator.discount.value);


     afterDiscount=price - ( price*discount/100 );

       document.discountCalculator.price.value=price.toFixed(2);
       document.discountCalculator.discount.value=discount.toFixed(2);
       document.discountCalculator.afterDiscount.value=afterDiscount.toFixed(2);

    }
```

Comment: post your html structure.

Comment: Also, your other javascript. If the value appears then disappears, something else is removing it.

Comment: Where is this JavaScript code being run?

Answer (score 3):

i just tried your code and it works fine. see if you have anything missing

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
   var price=0, discount=0, afterDiscount=0;
    price = Number(document.discountCalculator.price.value);
    discount = Number(document.discountCalculator.discount.value);


 afterDiscount=price - ( price*discount/100 );

   document.discountCalculator.price.value=price.toFixed(2);
   document.discountCalculator.discount.value=discount.toFixed(2);
   document.discountCalculator.afterDiscount.value=afterDiscount.toFixed(2);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="discountCalculator" >
    <input type="text" name="price" >
    <input type="text" name="discount" >
    <input type="text" name="afterDiscount" >
</form>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="calculate()">
</body>
</html>
```